# Discord.py - Why my bot sends every message twice?

Tags: python, discord, pycharm, bots

I'm making a Discord bot in Python and out of nowhere my bots keep replying twice to every command.

I don't link it to that, but it started when I accidentally enabled IdeaVim plugin and used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (nothing worked in that way, it should). When I disabled IdeaVim, the bot started to reply to every command twice. Like... To every.

Comment: You're probably just running it twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try restarting your computer. It is likely you are running your bot program twice.